# How to eliminate variable $t$ from the equations to solve this question?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, projectile

> A ball rolls horizontally off the top of a stairway with a speed of $1.52~\text{m/s}$. The steps are $20.3~\text{cm}$ high and $20.3~\text{cm}$ wide. Which step does the ball hit first?

I tried to solve by dividing the velocity vector into horizontal and vertical component. Horizontal Displacement will be $1.52 \cos0 \times t = 1.52t$. The vertical displacement would be $
(1.52 \times \sin0)t - \frac{gt^2}{2} = -4.9t^2$
But I can't figure out how to eliminate or find $t$. Even if we are given the total vertical and horizontal displacement, How to find on which step it would land first?

Comment: This H.C.Verma's problem!

Comment: How don't you know to eliminate $t$? You said by yourself that $x = 1.52t$. Then $t = x/1.52$ and introducing in $y$ you get $y = -4.9$ x $(x/1.52)^2$. What's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The steps inclination is 100% which means that for each meter of vertical distance, the steps go 1m of horizontal distance. Now, this means that the ball will hit the stairs almost immediately after the distance traveled vertically becomes equal than the distance traveled horizontally since the vertical speed is accelerating due to gravity.

The distance traveled horizontally (from when the ball rolls over the first step) as you've stated is $1.52t$ and the vertical is $gt^2/2$.

So when $1.52t=gt^2/2$ you know that that's when your ball has crossed the inclination level and is about to hit the step. Now solving for $t$ in $f(t)= (g/2)t^2-1.52t$  is easy.

When you find $t$ calculate the horizontal distance traveled $s=1.52t$ and divide by the step width to find which step it hits $StepHit=s/0.203$ (don't forget to round it upwards).

Answer (score 1):

What you should do is see which function hits 20.3 first. What's t when horizontal displacement is 20.3? If we put that t into vertical displacement equation, what displacement value do we get? Does the ball hit the first step or does it fly over it?

[image: pardon the crappy drawing.]

Comment: I don't understand why this answer got a minus. If it is wrong, then, fist, a better answer should be proposed.